# Excel - Return values between conditions of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that have Measure in meters, Value, and Distance columns (see attached screenshot). The Distance simply returns the difference between each row of the Measure column.

What I want to do is every time the Distance is greater than 10m (which I've used conditional formatting to highlight green), return in column E the measure values from the previous row up to the previous green cell, kind of like grouping them and displaying as a range. Then also return the min and max Value within that range of rows (probably in column F & G).

Ex. E6 would return something like "148000-148040" in text format, E16 would be "148090-148180", E17 would just be "148200". Then F6 = -91.09, G6 = -43.91, F16 = 15.49, G16 = 138.06 and so on.

Not sure if this would require VBA, but if it can be done with formulas that'd be great.

Sorry if this is confusing or if a similar question has been asked before.
Thank you!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The edit queue is full right now, but if you edit your post to format your screenshot link with [![screenshot][1]][1] it will show up without a link

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? Also, do you want the results in column E to be negative (the smaller number, 148000 minus the larger number, 148040?

Comment: @TomSharpe I have Microsoft 365 so probably the latest version, says version 2107 under About. And sorry for the confusion, but that's supposed to be displaying a range in text format, so it'd be pulling both numbers. although returning them separately is fine too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly! Will have a look at this in the morning if no-one else has answered by then.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this demonstrates the power of the new (ish) Xlookup very well (in this case, using backwards search):

For the range:

```
=IF(D3=10,"",XLOOKUP(TRUE,D2:D$2>10,B2:B$2,B$2,0,-1)&"-"&B2)
```

Min:

```
=IF(D3=10,"",MIN(XLOOKUP(TRUE,D2:D$2>10,C2:C$2,C$2,0,-1):C2))
```

Max:

```
=IF(D3=10,"",MAX(XLOOKUP(TRUE,D2:D$2>10,C2:C$2,C$2,0,-1):C2))
```

[image]

Comment: Good, I'm glad it worked for you. I found out a couple of things I didn't know about xlookup as well - like the fact that it delivers a reference, so you can use the result as one end of a range.